# Which is more correct, $\| \vec{a} \|$ or $|\vec{a}|$?

Tags: notation, vectors

The question is pretty self explanatory, but I’ve encountered situations where, for the length of some vector $\vec{a}$, to denote the length (or magnitude, which ever you prefer) as either $\| \vec{a}\|= \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots+a_n^2}$ or $|\vec{a}|= \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots+a_n^2}$ and I was wondering which notation is more widely accepted, per say? I’ve tried researching this and different websites actually use different notation.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I would say bold face, no arrows, no hats, and double bars.  If I am not using Latex, I underline my vectors to identify them as vectors.  But, the notations that mathematicians use and the notation physicists and engineers use is not always consistent.

Comment: This is largely a matter of opinion (and sometimes context), but I'd always use $\lVert a \rVert$ for the length of a vector, and reserve $|z|$ for the absolute value of a complex number.

Comment: To typeset what @DougM said: use $\lVert\bf a\rVert$, not $\lvert\vec a\rvert$.

Comment: Just use $|a|$. Boldface, arrows, and double bars are unnecessary. If you're confusing the absolute value of a complex number with the norm of a vector, you have deeper notational problems than can be fixed by adding an extra pair of bars. Besides, it agrees with the obvious isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$, etc.) and the one-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @anomaly I think that boldface is extremely helpful in distinguishing vectors from their components. For instance, ${\bf x} \cdot {\bf y}$ looks like a dot product to me, wherease $x \cdot y$ looks like the product of two real numbers. Context is important, of course, but we often see vectors and real numbers together, e.g., ${\bf v} = [v_1 \cdots v_n]^T$.

Comment: @Théophile: Would you also want a separate notation for the product of two matrices, a matrix with a vector, a vector with a scalar, a function with a constant, etc.? The distinction between $v$ and $v_i$ in $v = (v_1, \dots, v_n)$ seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: I prefer the German practice of using fraktur (\mathfrak{a}) $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{x}, \mathfrak{v}$,etc. for most vectorish things.  For matrices, and tensors of rank >1, I try to use upper case fraktur.  $\mathfrak{A}, \mathfrak{M}, \mathfrak{R}$  One exception is that it is sometimes nice to indicate a path or curve using lower case Greek letters with over-arrows. $\vec{\gamma}$.  Consistency, clarity, and aesthetics are what really matter.  I use $\hat{\mathfrak{e}_i}$ for unit basis vectors, and omit the hat for general basis vectors. $\mathfrak{e}_i$

Comment: @anomaly I like to use bold, uppercase variables for matrices: ${\bf Ax} = {\bf y}$.

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/raumzeitmateriev00weyl#page/18/mode/2up

Comment: @Théophile: Why? That just makes it uglier without any real benefit.

Comment: @anomaly Some matters come down to personal preference. I don't find it ugly, and the benefit (to me, at least) is that I understand at a glance this notation:
$${\bf A} = [{\bf a}_1 \cdots {\bf a}_n],\\ {\bf a_i} = [a_{1i}\cdots a_{mi}]^T$$
much more easily than this one:
$$a = [a_1 \cdots a_n],\\ a_i = [a_{1i}\cdots a_{mi}]^T$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitions are not judged "correct" or "incorrect".  Both of your notations are used in various contexts in mathematics.  There is a problem only if the writer and the reader do not understand each other.

Answer (score 4):

You see both sets of notation. For vectors you see ${\bf v}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\underline{v}$, perhaps others. For the norm you see $|\cdot|$ and $\| \cdot \|$. It depends if you're in high-school or university, do physics or pure maths.

As a mathematician, I prefer $\|{\bf v}\|$ for the norm of a vector. By hand, that would be written as $\| \underline{v}\|$, but that's just because it's hard to write bold font by hand.

(Same reason we use $\mathbb R$ for what was traditionally ${\bf R}$)

I like to use $|\cdot|$ for the modulus function, a.k.a. absolute value, which applies to scalars. It might seem silly when both $|\cdot|$ and $\| \cdot \|$ measure "size" in some way, but it makes it easier for the reader to see what is a vector and what is a scalar.

(To be technical: A vector space has a set of vectors, and an accompanying scalar field. There is often an idea of "size" in the vector space, and an idea of "size" in the scalar field. I like to use $\| \cdot \|$ for the norm in the vector space and $| \cdot |$ for the norm in the scalar field.)

For example, given two intersecting lines with respective direction vectors ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$, the acute angle of intersection $\theta$ satisfies $|{\bf u} \cdot {\bf v}| = \|{\bf u}\| \|{\bf v}\| \cos\theta$. The scalar/inner/dot product ${\bf u} \cdot {\bf v}$ is a scalar, and so $|{\bf u} \cdot {\bf v}|$ is the absolute value/modulus of that scalar. On the other hand ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$ are vectors and $\|{\bf u}\|$ and $\|{\bf v}\|$ are the norms of those vectors.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, it really depends on the context. Both are widely accepted and understood. However, the nice thing is, that the two notations allow you to distinguish between two notions of "length". So in one extreme, in an introductory course on vectors I would write
$$\|a\| = \sqrt{|a_1|^2+ |a_2|^2+...+|a_n|^2}$$
to explicitely distinguish the notion of absolute value in the real numbers and length of a vector.

In the other extreme, if I am later interested in some basic functional analysis, I would instead use notation
$$\|f\| = \sqrt{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)|^2 dx}$$
for some function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where then
$$|f(x)| = \sqrt{f_1(x)^2+...+f_n(x)^2},$$
this time to explicitely distinguish between the $L^2$ norm of a function and the length of its value at $x$.

**edit**: I did not put vector arrows here, because I personally do not use them, however this answer of course also works with $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{f}$.

Answer (score -3):

The first one is the more correct, in the sense that is preferable when you are dealing both with vectors and numbers and it is necessary to avoid misunderstanding.

The notation $|\cdot|$ indicates the absolute value for numbers, but it is also frequently and widely used for vectors when it is clear from the context.

Comment: I think that your answer will be more appreciated if you use punctuation and begin your sentences with capital letters. As it stands, it isn't clear whether you've finished your thoughts or not.

Comment: thanks, I really don't understand all the downvotes :(